# Rename folders in c# Form

Tags: c#, winforms, string, rename

i try to make a Form program in c# to rename a lot of folders. The Customers has to choose the folder (and the name to rename), where all the folders are include, for example in c:\folders\ are this folders:

```
1991 - title1
1992 - title2
1993 - title3
1994 - title4
```

And now i will change the year into a name, like this:

```
name - title1
name - title2
name - title3
name - title4
```

Example pic:

[image: example program]

I hope you unterstand what i want :-) and you can help me with this.

Regards,
matthias

Comment: yes, I do understand what you want, but I ain't gonna write the code for you. This is a Q&A page, so please post specific problems where you have a problem solving them.

Comment: i'm new in c#, but i think what carra wrote is good for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few hints:

1. Get all files (recursively if you
   want) with

   Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\folder\")
2. Rename all files with

   File.Move(@"C:\folder\oldname",
   @"C:\folder\newname");

If your file format is like that you can simply split the filename at "-" & replace the first part with your name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [FolderBrowserDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog.aspx) to select the directory, the [Directory class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) to rename it and `String.Split` or a RegEx to modify the name.

Store the selected directories and their names to a collection of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The Directory Class will do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx

You should also take a look at Path to help figure out what to replace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_members(v=VS.71).aspx

```
// Move the directory.
Directory.Move(path, target);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use others  answers and for renaming i would do a RegEx replace like this.

```
string new_folder_name = Regex.Replace(/*old folder name*/, @"\d\d\d\d", /*user provided name*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt the following

```
for /L %n in (1991,1,2010) do ren "(%n) - *" "name - *"
```

should do what you want.