# Rename Folder - shouldnt exit on missing folder

Tags: c#, rename

I want to rename folder in directory with C# and I write below code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    System.IO.Directory.Move(@"E:\scan\" + datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value, @"E:\scan\" + datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
```

cell 0 is number and cell 1 is name
I want replace number with name

its ok when folder is exist same number in datagridview else if dont exist (number) occur exception
I want if dont exist folder in directory with same number in datagridview, continue to end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename folders in c# Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907572/rename-folders-in-c-sharp-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023975/renaming-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @BarmanSoft - whats your native language?

Comment: There's a `Directory.Exists()` method, and you can use `try { ... } catch { ... }` to avoid "exiting" on unexpected exceptions. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the directory exists with System.IO.Directory.Exists(directoryPath).
In your case the code would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"E:\scan\" + datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.Move(@"E:\scan\" + datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value, @"E:\scan\" + datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`Directory.Exists(string)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, for the sake of brevity, you might want to import the `System.IO` namespace. See [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var sourceFolder = @"E:\scan\" + datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
    var destinationFoler = @"E:\scan\" + datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    if (Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
    {
        Directory.Move(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
    }
    else
    {
        // Warn the user. E.g.
        // MessageBox.Display("Directory not found.");
    }
}
```